# Session in Android httpclient to Webview in Google App Engine

Tags: android, google-app-engine, session, cookies, webview

I followed [Nick's tutorial](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/05/Authenticating-against-App-Engine-from-an-Android-app) in Authenticating agains App Engine from an Android App.

I already have the tokens. How can I used this token to open the appengine site in the android webview? What i mean is that I have webapp e.g. example.appspot.com and I want to open this in android webview after the authentication in native android part.

This is part of Nick's tutorial:

```
private class GetCookieTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... tokens) {
        try {
            // Don't follow redirects
            http_client.getParams().setBooleanParameter(ClientPNames.HANDLE_REDIRECTS, false);
            HttpGet http_get = new HttpGet("https://example.appspot.com/_ah/login?continue=http://localhost/&auth=" + tokens[0]);
            HttpResponse response;
            response = http_client.execute(http_get);
            if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 302)
                // Response should be a redirect
                return false;

            for(Cookie cookie : http_client.getCookieStore().getCookies()) {
                if(cookie.getName().equals("ACSID"))
                    return true;
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            http_client.getParams().setBooleanParameter(ClientPNames.HANDLE_REDIRECTS, true);
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        new AuthenticatedRequestTask().execute("http://example.appspot.com/home");
    }
}
```